# How to import data from an excel file when report is using an existing power bi dataset?

Tags: powerbi

I have a power bi report that connects to another power bi dataset.

I want to import an excel file into the new report's dataset without making any changes to the original dataset.

On this new report (that uses another dataset) the transform query button is grayed out so I'm not sure how to import an excel file. Does power bi support this?

Answer (score 1):

What you`re looking for is a **Composite Model**. If you want to use it, you first have to enable the following **Preview features** in *Options*:

[image]

After a restart you can click on *Transform data* and Power BI will add a local model and allow you to add further data sources like **Excel files** to it.

Comment: Are you sure? This video seems to show how to do this: https://youtu.be/g-nRxDVt3To - can you revise your answer. Watch from 1.25 onwards.

Comment: You're right. Just follow the steps in the video, but make sure you have the according preview features enabled that I'm showing in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Get data button on the home tab. Should be a simple upload of the excel file. Make sure to use the desktop version. Using the model tab on the far left side you can link variables (many to many, many to one, etc.) (if the datasets are related)

Comment: It's disabled when I'm connected to live to pbi dataset